# Objective C/NSMutableDictionary - [NSCFSet objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector

Tags: objective-c, exception, nsmutabledictionary

I do not understand what I am doing wrong. I have a dictionary as a property of a singleton class:

```
@interface CABResourceManager : NSObject
{
.... 
    NSMutableDictionary* soundMap;
}
@property (retain) NSMutableDictionary *soundMap;
```

Then I add an object to this dictionary in one class method:

```
+ (void)loadSoundFromInfo:(ABSoundInfo)sound
{
    static unsigned int currentSoundID = 0;
    CABSound* newSound = [[CABSound alloc] initWithInfo:(ABSoundInfo)sound soundID:++currentSoundID];
    [[CABResourceManager sharedResMgr].soundMap setObject:newSound forKey:sound.name];
}
```

And try to get it in another method:

```
+ (ALuint)playSoundByName:(NSString*)name
{
    NSMutableDictionary* map = [CABResourceManager sharedResMgr].soundMap;
    CABSound *sound = [map objectForKey:name];   // here comes the exception
```

and the app exits on exception by that.

```
2011-03-27 20:46:53.943 Book3HD-EN[5485:207] *** -[NSCFSet objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x226950
2011-03-27 20:46:53.945 Book3HD-EN[5485:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'
```

I guess it might have something with memory management, but hier it looks clear for me: CABSound object is retained in dictionary by doing setObject(), it should not be released at this time.

Answer (score 1):

I'd check that soundMap is properly initialized. It looks like soundMap is a bad pointer at the time you get the error. It might happen to be nil in +loadSoundFromInfo, which wouldn't produce an error right away.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've initialized your soundMap in designated initializer:

```
// - (id) init... or something else
soundMap = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Dont forget to override default dealloc implementation:

```
// class implementation file
- (void)dealloc {
  [soundMap release];
  //...release other objects you own...
  [super dealloc];
}
```